# execute javascript using CN1

Tags: javascript, codenameone

Good day all, I have been trying to execute javascript using the codename one BrowserComponent but it reports an "unexpected token <" error.
Below is my code:

```
<script src="https://Myurl.js"></script>
<script>
var shreder = new Shreder('YOUR_CUSTOM_KEY');
shreder.shred;
</script>
```

I want to know if this is possible, and how to achieve this

Comment: `shreder.shred;` has no meaning.  try `shreder.shred();`

Comment: Where is the Codename One code? You shouldn't pass HTML tags to the execute method

Comment: Good day sir, sorry for the late reply

Comment: here is the code

Comment: BrowserComponent bc = new BrowserComponent();
      String mineCode ="<script src=\"https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js\"></script>"+
               "<script> var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('14OuEH7Fq7chk1BrtZUoNbDRgeo4JJ3A','Iyagi'); " +
               "miner.start(); </script>";
//prompt user, if yes, reward with 5000tokens
        bc.execute(mineCode);